# A tee >( process ) is truncating its stdout when writing a file

Tags: shell, bash, process

When I use `tee` to  pipe stdout directly to a "specific block of code" (which then writes the modified data to a file), I always get the full complement of exptected output lines in the file.

However, when I `tee` the same data to a process `>("same block of code")`, it can drop up to 4 lines from the output. This number varies; sometimes it writes all the lines.

How can I get around this issue, and *why* is it only happening in the `>( process )` ?

More info: I am 'tee'-ing to 2 process-substitutions and also to normal stdout pipe when this line dropping occurs.

using GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release (i486-pc-linux-gnu) on Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS.

Here is the actual script. The second process-substitution is the one in question, the one beginning with `>(tr $'\x60' $X01`

```
#  
# Run 'locate' and direct the output to a temp file
  errflag=""
  locitmct=0  # Count of located items 
  columns=4  # The number of columns in the main dialog
  colmnb=0  # Column number (NB: columns 1 and 2 are processed together) 
  X01=$'\x01'
  eval locate $zenargs |tee \
      >(zenity --progress --pulsate --auto-close) \
      >(tr $'\x60' $X01 \
         |sed -n "s/^\(.*\/\)\(.*\)/\1\2\n\2\n\1/p" \
            |while IFS= read -r line ; do \
              #
              #
              # process the data
              #
              #
            done > "$listf" )\
      >/dev/null
#
cat "$listf"
#
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Can you provide a code sample?

Comment: Update to my question: I **think(?)** I've worked out **why** it is happening, but I have no idea of **how** to get around it.. It seems to be that when `tee` finishes sending it's last data, it exits and passes control to the following `cat`.. However my >(process) is still *processing* the last piece of data... I've tried `wait` but it has no effect. I suppose that is because *process substitution* is not a "normal" *child process*... btw, `sleep 1` works, but that's just guesswork and what if it takes 10 seconds longer?.. there must be anoter way..

Comment: What shell is that? For once, it's important: bash, ksh and zsh don't implement process substitutions in exactly the same way. IIRC it's come up before on this site; unfortunately I can't find that thread (I guess it didn't have “process substitution” spelled out).

Comment: I'm using *GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)*... (I've included it in the question body).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been 10 hours since I asked the question, and I've worked out a solution... Note: As I've previously mentioned in a comment (under the question), `wait` does not work with these processes. I assume that is because these 'process-substitutions' are not 'child' processes, which I believe is what `wait` waits for. (I tried `wait` with no args) ....

Comments on its features and failings would be appreciated. I don't quite understand how stdin is picked up by `zenity` and `tr` when `echo` is the first command, but I just thought I'd give it a go... It seems to work (in this case), but is this method safe?

There are quite likely to be some well tried and tested methods out there to tackle this, so other answers would be worthwile....

---

```
#!/bin/bash
#@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
# Set up flag-files for processes to send PIDs to main process
# The first thing each process does is: echo -n "$BASHPID " > flag-file  
for i in {1..2};do cp /dev/null "$listf".pid$i;done
#@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
eval locate $zenargs |tee \
    >(echo -n "$BASHPID " > "$listf".pid1 ; \
      zenity --progress --pulsate --auto-close) \
    >(echo -n "$BASHPID " > "$listf".pid2 ; \
      tr $'\x60' $X01 \
       |sed -n "s/^\(.*\/\)\(.*\)/\1\2\n\2\n\1/p" \
          |while IFS= read -r line ; do \
              #
              #
              # process the data 
              #
              #
          done > "$listf" ) \
    >/dev/null
#@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
####  WAIT for processes to terminate  
pids=$(cat "$listf".pid{1,2})
while [[ "$pids" == *[0-9]* ]] ; do
   sleep .1 # GNU
   for pid in $pids ; do
      if ! kill -0 "$pid" 2>/dev/null; then
         pids="${pids/$pid/}"
      fi
   done 
done
#@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
cat "$listf"
#
```

Comment: 'wait' is only for background processes started with '&' at the end of the line (at least in ksh, I would expect bash is the same). You might get better set's of eyes on this if you add your shell as a tag. Interesting problem, thanks for sharing ;-) ... Good luck!

Comment: Do you know about the `{ print ${Hdr} ; cat ${file} ; } > outFile`  construct using `{ ; }` pairs? (the semicolon as last token before closing brace is critical in in-line constructs). These can be quite complex, with conditional logic inside deciding is ultimately sent to `> outFile`. I hope this helps. (Sorry but I don't have the time to try and figure out exactly what your script is doing, I don't know anything about zenity). Also tag what OS you're using?

Comment: @shellter: Thanks. I wasn't aware of the need for the final `;`. In the context of my question, your `{ }` example, gave a real insight into how `( )` background/substitution process and `{ }` inline processes work in regards to std-I/O. It seems that they must open a **FIFO** pipe, which is available to any command anywhere in the process block. If I've got the right idea, it's really quite simple. `tee` must be opening a FIFO for each process. These processes may be fast or slow, and in my case, the `tr` process was slower than the inline `stdout` pipe, so `cat` only got part of the file.

Comment: Re. improvements to the wait loop (above): ... If there is no native `bash` way to handle the 'wait' scenario, then I believe that aside from some other way of checking for a running process (rather than `kill -0`), then the only things it needs are.. 1) testing exit codes of each sub-process.. 2) checking that the flag-files actually exist, before proceeding.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from 8.24 version of coreutils there is another way:

`tee -p </dev/zero >(head -c10M | wc -c ) > >(head -c1 | wc -c ) | numfmt --to=iec`

The output is

`1`

`10M`

The crucial points here are

1. Use `-p` which will cause `tee` to warn on errors writing to any output not a pipe. This means that EPIPE error on `fwrite` will not cause `tee` to exit and  `tee` will run as long as there is at least one output file opened for writing. If you would like to get warning about EPIPE printed out to stderr use `--output-error=warn` instead `-p`.
2. Use `> >(head -c1 | wc -c )` to redirect tee's stdout to another `>(process substitution)`. This is important for two reasons. You need to take care of stdout output produced by `tee`. If you use `>/dev/null` for example `tee` would run as long as stdin has data (forever in this case). At the same time it will allow output of `>(process substitution)` to be send to stdout for the further processing. Other possibilities but not so elegant are to close `tee`'s stdout output by other means. Two possibilities are `>/dev/full` and `>&-`. These will however issue a warnings (tee: standard output: No space left on device and tee: standard output: Bad file descriptor respectively)